# Как найти 2 ошибки в таблице IDEF1X?

Tags: база-данных

нужно 2 ошибки в таблице формата IDEF1X. 1 ошибка найдена в формате последнего блока в названии, предположу что 2 ошибка тоже в названии[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Названия - штука отфонарная. Лишь бы уникальным было в своей области, ну и синтаксический контроль проходило. А потому формально в этой схеме ошибок нет в принципе. Или есть некие дополнительные соглашения и условия, которые Вы "забыли" озвучить.

Comment: Найди 10 отличий. Как-то так выглядит вопрос.

Comment: Дополнительных условий нет. Только цитирую слова преподавателя "ошибка связанна со стандартом IDEF1X". Должно было быть 2 ошибки как я понял в названии блоков, 1-ну ошибку которую я нашел это последний блок "Продукция противогазов" там надо писать просто "продукция" и ниже там же указанно "код противогаза" должен быть просто "код". Ну и судя по всему 2-ая ошибка идет такого же типа

Comment: А калькуляция сама собой подразумевает операции, или же этот пункт упущен намеренно?

Comment: калькуляция скорее не операции, а продукт поставки

Comment: Какая то ошибка по типу ошибки которую я уже нашел, что указанна выше, но я не разберусь какая

Comment: Так не кто не даст адекватный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

в табличке Калькуляция есть внешний ключ на таблицу Продукция, и называется он почему то Код противогаза!

Comment: а как должен называться?

Comment: Код продукта, и тоже самое должнобыть в табличке Строка заказа

Comment: конечно если посудить идеологически, там много чего не правильно)

Comment: а по конкретнее? что именно не правильно еще?

Comment: таблица Строка заказа, там есть foreign key на таблицу Покупатель и Сотрудники, зачем?, если это уже указанно в таблице Заказ.
таблица Сырье, нет связи с Поставщиком!
таблица Калькуляция там есть foreign key на таблицу Сырье, зачем?, должна быть связь с Поставщиком.

Comment: Вот что пишет преподаватель, цитирую: как корректно именовать сущности? и вот как?)

Comment: на латинице) и чтоб имя отражало назначение сущности)

Comment: что именно на латинице? где конкретно не правильно то?)

Comment: какой определенный блок?)

Comment: все должно именоваться на латинице

Comment: нет, должна быть ошибка конкретно в названии блока, одна единственная ошибка, помимо конечного блока

Comment: я Вам уже перечислил все возможные варианты)

Comment: так про ошибку в каком блоке так и не перечислили) Сказали только то что на латинице должно быть, так это не ошибка касающаяся моей проблемы. Я говорю ошибка в каком то блоке в названии и только, и она одна

Comment: конкретно, я Вам не могу сказать, я Вам перечислил все возможные варианты, а там сами смотрите уже!

Comment: ну спасибо конечно, но все перечисленные варианты увы не подходят, так как не один из вариантов не идет в ответ на заданный мне вопрос

Comment: ок) совет напоследок подучите теорию, потом может получится и самому разбираться в подобных проблемах

Comment: Да было бы не плохо, не прочел бы я ее 3 раза

Comment: может это занятие все таки не для Вас)

Comment: Да я 3 года назад понял что это занятие не для меня, но диплом уже через месяц, так что поздно оборачиваться назад