# Как найти 2 ошибки в таблице IDEF1X?

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, блок-схема

Задание: Нужно найти 2 ошибки в тексте, ошибка по от "стандарт IDEF1X".
Одна ошибка найдена и вычеркнута, вопрос где вторая?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898069